# Hide link when table is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a horizontal website that keeps displaying my tables/images (my images are in tables) when you click the 'more' link at the bottom. I am trying to make it so that when my last image/table is visible, the 'more' link disappears. I am very new at coding but I managed to compile this but it's not working.

I read that CSS always recognizes an element as visible as long as it fits within the page, and that Javascript must be used to check if it is actually visible on a page. Any solution is appreciated, thanks.

```
<script src="./lib/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
    function() {
        if($('#finaltable').is(':visible')){
            $('#morelink').remove(this);
        }
    }
</script>
<html>
    //There are about 20 tables but the last one is ID'd as 'final table'
    <table id="finaltable">
        <tr><td>Final Table</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use jquery :visible, because it's based only on the fact that your element has CSS display different that none (its parents as well) and its width and height greater than 0. [references](http://blog.jquery.com/2009/02/20/jquery-1-3-2-released/#visible-hidden-overhauled)

In your case, I would use the offset property. On the click event on the "More" button to check where is the final table.

```
<a id="more" href="#">More></a>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
      $("#more").on("click",function(e)
      {
        //finaltable display on screen
        if($("#finaltable").offset().left<=0)
        {
          $("#more").hide();
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, just to be sure. You have multiple tables scrolling from right to left when you click on "more", right?

Comment: So, when you click on "more", the displayed table n goes right, and the table n+1 comes from left?

Comment: Yes, when you click 'more' the new tables go to the right of the existing ones. The old ones stay where they are, only the newly displayed ones go to the right. Not sure what you mean about n+1.

Comment: OK, I ll build a quick fiddle, hope I understood the workflow.

Comment: Have a look to that and let me know it matches what you want to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/8dCFR/

Answer (score 0):

Refer to `window.scrollY` in a `setTimeout` to determine if your are nearing the bottom of the page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.scrollY

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a function in JavaScript but not calling it. You could write the following code.

```
   /* Declare the function */
    var f = function() {
       if($('#finaltable').is(':visible')){
           $('#morelink').remove();
       }
    }

   /* Call the function */
   jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
      f(); 
   });
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/muxYp/) of the code.

Comment: The last part, "f();" goes right before the </script> right? I put it all in but it doesnt work :(

Comment: Yes, the f() goes before the </script>. You need to put the <script> tag after the html elements #finaltable and #morelink of call the function using document.ready(), I made an edit in my question.

Comment: You mean tag my html table? Sorry can you show me how that looks like?

Comment: Thank you so much. It still isnt working for me though :( so I will try the other solution..

Comment: I added e demo link in jsfiddle. @Yoann has a good point in his answer about :visible.